# Countif data does not equal any number in a range

Tags: google-sheets, filter, match, unique, countif

I'm working on a Google Sheet where I am entering zipcode information.  Column A will have zip codes received from survey respondents.

Columns B, C, D and E include reference lists of zipcodes in different areas.  I need to know how many respondents live in each group of zipcodes, so I'm using this formula to tally that:

```
=sumproduct(countif(A2:A1000,B2:B1000))
```

I'm looking for a formula to capture any number entered in Column A that doesn't match any of my reference zip codes in columns B, C, D and E.

I've tried:

```
=sumproduct(countif(A2:A1000,<>B2:B1000))
```

and am getting a formula parse error.

Most of the examples I'm seeing are using really small datasets, so they're using a formula like `=sumproduct(countif(A2:A1000,<>"DATA"))`, but I am working with large data ranges, so that's not particularly helpful.

Some other examples I've seen that seem similar are being recommended formulas that are more complex than what I'm familiar with, so I'm not able to pick apart what might be useful to me.

### Edit: Sample data

| A Column | Area B | Area C | Area D | Area E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 78040 | 72744 | 90806 | 55975 | 73098 |
| 71369 | 65501 | 26743 | 56051 | 79022 |
| 13375 | 85739 | 40830 | 18640 | 51461 |
| 24312 | 45333 | 54554 | 35211 | 54821 |
| 44089 | 84656 | 50612 | 31326 | 95471 |
| 70762 | 17087 | 25387 | 24312 | 30650 |
| 73098 | 50611 | 60435 | 77612 | 49712 |
| 79022 | 8316 | 28204 | 51245 | 97450 |
| 37668 | 75495 | 46381 | 94539 | 72014 |
| 43021 | 21056 | 32212 | 57249 | 26542 |
| 84656 | 43152 | 26691 | 38345 | 30116 |
| 44188 | 29848 | 27966 | 71369 | 95683 |
| 25387 | 17881 | 99701 | 62474 | 53593 |
| 85974 | 98565 | 72088 | 22835 | 40517 |
| 50247 | 35572 | 34472 | 45732 | 99753 |
| 94279 | 20765 | 4463 | 32828 | 85718 |
| 56332 | 99031 | 45415 | 97520 | 41512 |
| 55303 | 43446 | 37803 | 94102 | 75803 |
| 81229 | 42061 | 95960 | 42036 | 98376 |
| 18640 | 15142 | 72031 | 39114 | 97026 |
| 53593 | 26448 | 23486 | 12915 | 7017 |
| 72785 | 6256 | 68661 | 19137 | 15696 |
| 46381 | 97753 | 17052 | 17880 | 93106 |
| 40517 | 83011 | 46710 | 52165 | 79539 |
| 51245 | 24566 | 56332 | 88116 | 15325 |
| 22162 |  |  |  |  |
| 24566 |  |  |  |  |
| 89041 |  |  |  |  |

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample data for you
Try this formula

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(A2:A, ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A,TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:E)) , FALSE))), "No Match")
```

[image]

### Explanation:

This formula is used to filter a range of values in column A based on whether they have a match in columns B to E. Let's break down the formula step by step:

1. `UNIQUE(B2:E)` returns a list of unique values from columns B to E. It creates a single column of unique values by stacking the values from those columns vertically.
2. `TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:E))` converts the column of unique values into a row by transposing it. This step is necessary because the MATCH function works with row vectors, and we want to compare it with the values in column A.
3. `MATCH(A2:A, TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:E)), FALSE)` compares each value in column A (A2:A) with the unique values in columns B to E. It returns the relative position of the matching value in the unique values list or an error value (#N/A) if there's no match.
4. `ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A, TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:E)), FALSE))` checks if there is an error (no match) for each value in column A. It returns an array of TRUE and FALSE values, where TRUE indicates no match and FALSE indicates a match.
5. `FILTER(A2:A, ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A, TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:E)), FALSE)))` filters the values in column A based on the array of TRUE and FALSE values obtained from the previous step. It returns only the values from column A that do not have a match in columns B to E.
6. **`IFERROR`**`(FILTER(A2:A, ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A, TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:E)), FALSE))), "No Match")` wraps the filtered values from step 5 with the IFERROR function. If the FILTER function returns any values, they are displayed. Otherwise, if there are no matches, it displays the text "No Match".

As required, the formula filters the values in column A and returns only those values that do not have a match in columns B to E. If there are no matches, it displays the text "No Match", You can replace "No Match" with "" to return nothing.

Used formulas help
[**`IFERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) - [**`FILTER`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) - [**`ISERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349) - [**`MATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) - [**`UNIQUE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en&sjid=12926676791125192248-EU)

Answer (score 1):

Simple `COUNTIFS()` should work with `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(A2:A,INDEX(COUNTIFS(B2:E,A2:A))=0)
```

[image]